# Scala outer => syntax

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “outer =>” really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353915/what-does-outer-really-mean)

where I can find the information on

```
trait After extends Context { outer => xxx
//...
}
```

What does it mean **outer =>**?

Comment: I think I already answered to this somewhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535657/scala-trait-syntax/11535791#11535791

Comment: @Edmondo1984: IMO, both answers are lacking. Yours is more concise but doesn't read like an answer to this question. There needs to be improvement before anything is deleted by roving mods looking for points.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a self type. You can also add a type annotation, to force the class, that extends your trait to be of a certain type. But without a type it is just a reference to `this` (and is called a self-reference), so you can use it in inner classes etc. E.g.:

```
class MyOuter { outer =>
  // this == outer
  class MyInner {
    // this != outer
    def creator = outer
  }
}
```

The other usage I mentioned can for example be used to add special behaviour to existing classes:

```
class MyClass {
  val foo = "foo"
}

trait MyClassExtension { this: MyClass =>
  def fooExtended(s: String) = foo + s
}

scala> val x = new MyClass with MyClassExtension
x: MyClass with MyClassExtension = $anon$1@5243618

scala> x.fooExtended("bar")
res3: java.lang.String = foobar
```

Here the `this: MyClass =>` means, that `MyClassExtension` can only be mixed into an instance or subclass of `MyClass`.

```
scala> class OtherClass
defined class OtherClass

scala> val x = new OtherClass with MyClassExtension
<console>:11: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type OtherClass with MyClassExtension does not conform to MyClassExtension's selftype MyClassExtension with MyClass
       val x = new OtherClass with MyClassExtension
```